# What is a Perforce "shelved" file?

Tags: perforce, shelving

In Perforce, what is a "shelved" file?  What is the purpose of shelving a file that is open for edit in the workspace?

Comment: See [Shelving: Pretty Darn Useful!](http://www.perforce.com/blog/091209/shelving-pretty-darn-useful) for a good explanation of the Perforce `shelve` command and example use cases.

Comment: Shelving stores copies of the file on the Perforce server, so it can be used as a quick backup of work in progress, not ready to be committed yet.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the Perforce [documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/shelve.html):

> Shelving is the process of temporarily
>   storing work in progress on a Perforce
>   Server without submitting a
>   changelist. Shelving is useful when
>   you need to perform multiple
>   development tasks (such as
>   interruptions from higher-priority
>   work, testing across multiple
>   platforms) on the same set of files,
>   or share files for code review before
>   committing your work to the depot.
>
> The p4 shelve command creates,
>   modifies, or discards shelved files in
>   a pending changelist. Shelved files
>   persist in the depot until they are
>   discarded (by means of p4 shelve -d)
>   or replaced by subsequent p4 shelve
>   commands.
>
> After shelving files, you can revert
>   or modify them in your client
>   workspace, and restore the shelved
>   versions of those files to your
>   workspace with the p4 unshelve
>   command. While files are shelved,
>   other users can unshelve the shelved
>   files into their own workspaces, or
>   into other client workspaces.
>
> Files that have been shelved can also
>   be accessed with the p4 diff, p4
>   diff2, p4 files, and p4 print
>   commands, using the revision specifier
>   @=change, where change is the pending
>   changelist number.
>
> If no arguments are specified, p4
>   shelve creates a new changelist, adds
>   files from the user's default
>   changelist, and (after the user
>   completes a form similar to that used
>   by p4 submit), shelves the specified
>   files into the depot. If a file
>   pattern is given, p4 shelve shelves
>   only the files that match the pattern.

Comment: The Perforce "shelve" command sounds similar in purpose to `git stash`, but where Git stores a stash in the local workspace (as it does with every change), Perforce "shelve" stores the changes in the depot.

Comment: I believe that `git stash` also automatically reverts (or in Git terms, resets) files in the workspace, where Perforce gives you the option to revert the files.